# Not using wingpanel, any widget for time and reboot on Odin's desktop?

Tags: wingpanel

I deactivated the wingpanel which was buggy on the old PC, but I would like to show the date/time and logout buttons on the desktop. (I kept Plank and what I beleive is Gala).

1 - After looking a bit around, it seems I could use some panel creator or launcher, would anyone know of a simple minimalist way to achieve this for Elementary OS Odin ?

2 - I would be happy to customize the right-clic-on-desktop context menu to show Applications and shutdown command but could not find how to do that ( I did put an Application menu in Plank, though).
I have an application called "Menu Principal" that allows to switch on and off some submenus for Application Menu, but nothing for the desktop menu. Where should I look for it ?

Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Give the docklets a try: Ctrl + right click the Dock -> Preferences -> Docklets -> drag the one you want in the Dock. There's a clock docklet too. If you add the Applications docklet, and then right click it, you'll get a simple menu with all your apps. If you also create a .desktop file with some logoff command ("gnome-session-quit --power-off " works on elementary) and add it to ~/.local/share/applications, you'll get access to that from right-clicking the applications docklet.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad , as suggested, I was able to use the docklets for the clock and Applications, and make some .desktop file to show reboot button in dock as well explained here : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/plank :)